# CSS - Rounded Select, Checkbox and Radiobutton

Tags: css

Is there any way, how to make rounded HTML `<select>`, without using any javascript?
I have this insane design and I have absolutely no idea how to do it only with **CSS**.

The same problem is with `checkbox` and `radiobutton`. Does anybody know how to make them rounded?

I need solution that works for IE6+, Firefox 2+, Opera 9+ ...

[alt text http://uploader.chytry.cz/select-checkbox.png](http://uploader.chytry.cz/select-checkbox.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Form styling is very problematic, there are no guarantees that any styling will work. Simple borders and background colours/images generally work OK in most browsers. I believe Safari will let you style very little. [Check this page](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200410/styling_even_more_form_controls/) for more detailed info.

Honestly, the best solution is to use javascript. [jQuery click menu](http://p.sohei.org/jquery-plugins/clickmenu/) is a great solution I used recently to mimic a select box (used JS to set a value on a hidden field when an element in the menu was selected).

I'm sure there are other solutions around too if you search.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Now the long answer: Internet Explorer does not lend itself well to being styled. You will be able to set a background image for the left-hand side (the text content) that has rounded corners, but the drop-down arrow will be fixed as the default browser.  You'll also find that the mousedown and mouseover states for the control will be fixed as the default style.

I think that in many cases, the ideal preferred design needs to be a little pragmatic about limitations in browser standards support.  Specifically, the problem that IE6 doesn't support a fair number and IE7 is only slightly more compliant.

Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 2):

no
please see this site for radiobutton and checkbox
http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2006/06/11/fancy-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 0):

No, Whit out javascript or jQuery you can not do this. But if you need with jQuery try this link. It contains the HTML select box with rounded corners by jQuery.

http://webworld-develop.blogspot.com/2011/11/cool-html-5-select-with-jquery-and-css.html